# Execute a script on the output change of watch

Tags: macos, bash, shell

In Mac OSX, how can I execute a script say `script.sh` when there is a change of output in a command monitored by `watch`?

Following watches the output of the script `update_checker.sh`:

```
watch -d ./update_checker.sh
```

I am looking for a similar functionality like:

```
watch -d --on-change='./script.sh' ./update_checker.sh
```

Feel free to suggest a better solution if the above command is not suitable or cannot do this. Use case I am targeting: 'Act on web page/api change'.